# iOS Framework addition failed due to a Cocoapods installation failure

Tags: ios, xcode, git, cocoapods

when i try to build my unity project for IOS, Unity creates an error related with Firebase and Cocoapods. I could not find any solution. Can you please advice me to solve the error.
Thanks

**Unity Console Error Message;**

iOS framework addition failed due to a CocoaPods installation failure. This will will likely result in an non-functional Xcode project.

After the failure, "pod repo update" was executed and succeeded. "pod install" was then attempted again, and still failed. This may be due to a broken CocoaPods installation. See: https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/troubleshooting.html for potential solutions.

pod install output:

> Analyzing dependencies [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible
> versions for pod "GoogleAppMeasurement":   In Podfile:
> Firebase/Analytics (= 6.32.2) was resolved to 6.32.2, which depends on
> Firebase/Core (= 6.32.2) was resolved to 6.32.2, which depends on
> FirebaseAnalytics (= 6.8.2) was resolved to 6.8.2, which depends on
> GoogleAppMeasurement (= 6.8.2)
>
> Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (~> 7.68) was resolved to 7.69.0, which depends
> on   GoogleAppMeasurement (~> 7.0)
>
> [33mWARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8
> encoding. Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:
>
> export LANG=en_US.UTF-8  [0m
>
> pod repo update output:
>
> Updating spec repo `cocoapods`   $ /usr/bin/git -C
> /Users/MacName/.cocoapods/repos/cocoapods fetch origin --progress
> $ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/MacName/.cocoapods/repos/cocoapods
> rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD   master   $ /usr/bin/git -C
> /Users/MacName/.cocoapods/repos/cocoapods reset --hard
> origin/master   HEAD is now at 43802ecd7335 [Add] iOS_Bootstrap
> 1.7.6.2
>
> [33mWARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8
> encoding. Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:
>
> export LANG=en_US.UTF-8  [0m
>
> remote: Enumerating objects: 28, done.           remote: Counting
> objects:   3% (1/28)           remote: Counting objects:   7% (2/28)
> remote: Counting objects:  10% (3/28)           remote: Counting
> objects:  14% (4/28)           remote: Counting objects:  17% (5/28)
> remote: Counting objects:  21% (6/28)           remote: Counting
> objects:  25% (7/28)           remote: Counting objects:  28% (8/28)
> remote: Counting objects:  32% (9/28)           remote: Counting
> objects:  35% (10/28)           remote: Counting objects:  39% (11/28)
> remote: Counting objects:  42% (12/28)           remote: Counting
> objects:  46% (13/28)           remote: Counting objects:  50% (14/28)
> remote: Counting objects:  53% (15/28)           remote: Counting
> objects:  57% (16/28)           remote: Counting objects:  60% (17/28)
> remote: Counting objects:  64% (18/28)           remote: Counting
> objects:  67% (19/28)           remote: Counting objects:  71% (20/28)
> remote: Counting objects:  75% (21/28)           remote: Counting
> objects:  78% (22/28)           remote: Counting objects:  82% (23/28)
> remote: Counting objects:  85% (24/28)           remote: Counting
> objects:  89% (25/28)           remote: Counting objects:  92% (26/28)
> remote: Counting objects:  96% (27/28)           remote: Counting
> objects: 100% (28/28)           remote: Counting objects: 100%
> (28/28), done.           remote: Compressing objects:   5% (1/17)
> remote: Compressing objects:  11% (2/17)           remote: Compressing
> objects:  17% (3/17)           remote: Compressing objects:  23%
> (4/17)           remote: Compressing objects:  29% (5/17)
> remote: Compressing objects:  35% (6/17)           remote: Compressing
> objects:  41% (7/17)           remote: Compressing objects:  47%
> (8/17)           remote: Compressing objects:  52% (9/17)
> remote: Compressing objects:  58% (10/17)           remote:
> Compressing objects:  64% (11/17)           remote: Compressing
> objects:  70% (12/17)           remote: Compressing objects:  76%
> (13/17)           remote: Compressing objects:  82% (14/17)
> remote: Compressing objects:  88% (15/17)           remote:
> Compressing objects:  94% (16/17)           remote: Compressing
> objects: 100% (17/17)           remote: Compressing objects: 100%
> (17/17), done.           remote: Total 18 (delta 11), reused 0 (delta
> 0), pack-reused 0           From https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs
> fa8f7a21d8aa..43802ecd7335  master     -> origin/master

Comment: For the LANG error see [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66098136](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66098136)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Firebase and Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK version specification in the Podfile are incompatible.

Firebase 6.x is compatible with Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK versions up to 7.67.0. After 7.67.1, Firebase 7.x is required.

Comment: Thank you so much. I downloaded latest version of Firebase a few days ago but i dont know how i downloaded the wrong one. Now, i downloaded and setup Firebase 7 and problem solved. I lost 2 days for this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Before changing Firebase version can check that all the packages used for Firebase have the same version.

E.g.: Analytics 8.1.0 and Messaging 8.9.0 -> Analytics 8.9.0 and Messaging 8.9.0

For me it did the trick.