# CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding. Consider adding the following to ~/.profile. export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

Tags: flutter, runtime-error

```
[!] An error occurred while processing the post-install hook of the Podfile.

undefined method `each_child' for #<Dir:0x00007ff3fa3555c0>
Did you mean?  each_slice

/Applications/FlutterSDK/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/podhelper.rb:54:in `block in flutter_additional_ios_build_settings'
/Applications/FlutterSDK/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/podhelper.rb:51:in `each'
/Applications/FlutterSDK/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/podhelper.rb:51:in `flutter_additional_ios_build_settings'
/Users/macpro5/Downloads/oos-master/ios/Podfile:39:in `block (3 levels) in from_ruby'
/Users/macpro5/Downloads/oos-master/ios/Podfile:38:in `each'
/Users/macpro5/Downloads/oos-master/ios/Podfile:38:in `block (2 levels) in from_ruby'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:179:in `post_install!'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:897:in `run_podfile_post_install_hook'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:885:in `block in run_podfile_post_install_hooks'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:145:in `message'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:884:in `run_podfile_post_install_hooks'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:329:in `block (2 levels) in create_and_save_projects'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/pods_project_writer.rb:61:in `write!'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:328:in `block in create_and_save_projects'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:307:in `create_and_save_projects'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:299:in `generate_pods_project'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:178:in `integrate'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:166:in `install!'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'

/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:899:in `rescue in run_podfile_post_install_hook'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:896:in `run_podfile_post_install_hook'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:885:in `block in run_podfile_post_install_hooks'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:145:in `message'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:884:in `run_podfile_post_install_hooks'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:329:in `block (2 levels) in create_and_save_projects'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/pods_project_writer.rb:61:in `write!'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:328:in `block in create_and_save_projects'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:307:in `create_and_save_projects'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:299:in `generate_pods_project'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:178:in `integrate'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:166:in `install!'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
WARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:

```
    export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.

Answer (score 1):

just change your cocoapos version to 1.10.2 to solve your problem.

first uninstall your current version (whatever it is)

In my case, i downgraded from version 1.11.1

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
```

Then just install the stable version (as of Nov 11, 2021)

```
sudo gem install cocoapods:1.10.2
```

and build your app again.

If still not working , delete the below from the build directory:

- Podfile
- Podfile.lock
- Pods (directory)
  and build.

It fixed it for me, twice in the last few days.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your settings there with typing `locale` into your terminal. If there is an empty string for LANG, you need to change that.

This can be done by adding the line `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` into your ~/.bashrc  or ~/.zshrc file (Depending on which terminal you are using).

After that restart your terminal, or type `source ~/.zshrc`.
Doublecheck if the changes are in place by checking `locale`.

After that you can try again `flutter run` in the terminal to start your flutter app